# How do I get the returning value of a function that can throw that I'm testing with XCTAssertNoThrow(...)

Tags: unit-testing, assert, xctest

I want to get the return value of a function that I'm testing for a subsequent test. The function if defined like this:

`func apple(banana: Banana) throws -> Cherry { ... }`

I can test that it throws when it should:

`XCTAssertThrowsError(try apple(banana: badBanana), "Didn't throw")`

I can test it doesn't throw when it shouldn't:

`XCTAssertNoThrow(try apple(banana: goodBanana), "Did throw")`

I was hoping to do this:

`XCTAssertNoThrow(let cherry = try apple(banana: goodBanana), "Did throw")`

and then check `cherry` is what I would expect, but I get the following error: `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'...`

How can I get the returned value (an object of type `Cherry` in this case) from the `XCTAssertNoThrow` test? Or is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one I like better; it doesn't cause testing to halt just because an unexpected error gets thrown. And it lets you add a message:

```
func CheckNoThrow<T>(
  _ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
  _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
  file: StaticString = (#filePath),
  line: UInt = #line
) -> T? {
  var r: T?
  XCTAssertNoThrow(
    try { r = try expression() }(), message(), file: file, line: line)
  return r
}
```

Comment: This the inverse of [XCTUnwrap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/3380195-xctunwrap), so it's probably better-named as `Wrap`.

Answer (score 13):

Simply call the function, and assert against the return value:

```
func test_apple_withGoodBanana_shouldReturnBingCherry() throws {
    let result = try apple(banana: goodBanana)

    XCTAssertEqual(result, .bing)
}
```

By marking the test method itself as `throws` we can call the `try` without `?` or `!`. If it throws, the test will fail.

Comment: This is fine if you don't have anything else in the test case.  If there are more asserts you'd like to make even after a failure, you'll want my suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050989/125349

Comment: The issue I find with this is when an exception is thrown the test fails but it just says "Unknown Test failure" which isn't very informative.

Comment: @DeclanMcKenna If you want more information about the exception, you can wrap the `try` in a `do`-`catch`, transform the exception into a string, and report it with `XCTFail`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this static function:

```
func XCTAssertSuccessReturn<T>(
  _ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
  in file: StaticString = #file,
  line: UInt = #line
  ) -> T {
  do {
    return try expression()
  } catch {
    XCTFail(
      error.localizedDescription,
      file: file,
      line: line
    )
    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
let encryptedData = XCTAssertSuccessReturn(try encrypter.encrypt(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every solution on here is nice with its own pros and cons. After trying them all out I like combining the error reporting of Dave and Vitali's answers with the simplicity of Jon's.

This gives information on the error thrown without a fatal error, returning an optional or executing subsequent XCTAssert statements after an error has been thrown.

```
func testApple() throws {
    let result = XCTNoThrow(try apple(banana: goodBanana)
    let result = try apple(banana: goodBanana)

    XCTAssertEqual(result, .bing)
}
```